# How to JIT c++ code with classes having virtual functions via LLVM?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, jit

I'm a bit confused. I'm trying to jit this primitive C++ code using LLVM and CLANG:

```
class Test {
    int _v;
public:
    Test() : _v(0) { }
    ~Test() { }
    void Set(int v) {
        _v = v;
    }
    int Get() {
        return _v;
    }
};

extern "C" Test* CreateTest() {
    return new Test;
}

extern "C" void DestroyTest(Test** o) {
        delete *o;
        *o = 0;
}
```

I got *llvm::Module* as a result of *clang::CompilerInstance* invocation. When I pass that module into *llvm::ExecutionEngine* I can obtain proper pointers to "*CreateTest*" and "*DestroyTest*" routines, and everything works fine.

However, if I make "*Test::Set*" and "*Test::Get*" **virtual** in my class specification, any *llvm::ExecutionEngine::getFunctionAddress()* fails in *RuntimeDyldImpl::ResolveExternalSymbols()*.

It reports a fatal error, something like "Program used external function ??_7type_info@@6B@ which could not be resolved", and terminates my host process.

How can I resolve that linking issue??

BTW, are there any linking tricks to invoke libc functions, like malloc, printf, etc. from jit code?